# Passport and Angular - save login after reload page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, coffeescript, passport.js

I did a Passport Authentication in my NodeJS application - on login page user send a request to server and server response with message or userdata. I have a factory:

```
.factory('User', ->
   name = false
   return {
     getName: -> name,
     setName: (newName) ->  name = newName,
   }
)
```

and in main controller i display user name on top of the page. My question is how to store this information after reaload page? I know i have to use sessions, so i think i can do http request in main cotroller and ask server is this user logged. But i don't know how to do this on server side. I'm using also Express 4.0

I was using this tutorial: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local